# Not able to connect to amazon RDS with MYSQL workbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds, rds

I am stuck here in connecting with RDS instance with MySQL workbench

I getting following error

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'visitorbook.cdokqvroltrt.us-west-   2.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)

I have configured my security group for inbound traffic from my IP for port 3306.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ssh tunnel` through the EC2 instance with your `pem` file. No need to change the security group. If DB connection works form ec2 instance, then it will work from local machine as well.

You can setup ssh tunneling option in workbench connection setting.