# Can't connect to MySQL on AWS from Workbench or CLI Error 10060

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

Over the last 24 hours I have created and re-created an AWS MySql instance and tried to connect from both MySQL Workbench and CLI from my Windows 10 laptop.  I have not been successful.  I have set up the database using the "Standard Create" and "Free Tier" templates ensuring that I am connected to the default VPC, the database is "publicly accessible", and using only "password authentication".

After the database has been created, I select the default security group associated with the DB instance, and change the "inbound" rules to accept "All" traffic from "All" protocols in "All" port ranges, from "All" sources (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0) as well as specific "MySQL/Aurora)" TCP on Port 3306 from "All" sources (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0).

[image: Inbound Rules Screenshot]

The "outbound" rules also allows "All" traffic from  "All" protocols in "All" port ranges, from "All" sources (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0) in case the problem is the response getting back to my laptop.

[image: Outbound Rules Screenshot]

This seems to cover the widely-accepted solutions for making this connection...but even still, I checked my Windows firewall and router to be confirm that port 3306 was not blocked.

Can anyone think of another possible cause for this connection issue? At this point, I must be missing something really simple-stupid, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
I have reviewed the similar issue here: https://serverfault.com/questions/706819/unable-to-connect-to-rds-instance-from-outside-vpc-error-2003-hy000-cant-con?newreg=5b9e8fe57f7644119d6c7e7ba91f2fb2

The route table associated with the 3 subnets for the VPC look like this (with an "igw"):

[image: Route Table Image]

**EDIT 2**
My RDS MySQL DB is standalone.  I do not have an EC2 instance running.  The only EC2 Resources I use are the Security Groups that are associated with my default VPC.

**EDIT 3**
I finally created a new account on AWS and a brand new mySql DB.  I also uninstalled all of my MySql products (Workbench, Server, Installer, etc) and reinstalled workbench.  I added one new inbound rule to enable all traffic/ports/sources.  With all of these changes, I was able to connect the very first time.  The only thing I noticed this time in setting up my database was that the default inbound rule included All Traffic/Ports/Protocols but with the source set to the default security group instead of an IP range.

I am leaving the question unanswered because I don't still know what caused this to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to connect to amazon RDS with MYSQL workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580181/not-able-to-connect-to-amazon-rds-with-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, thanks for the response.  The only thing I have in EC2 is my Security Groups.  I don't have an instance of a server running.  I have only set up RDS and S3.

Answer (score 0):

Under Connectivity, while you are creating a DB try to create a new VPC and DB Subnet group

new VPC security group makes sure you add inbound rule [all traffic] any pv4

Virtual private cloud (VPC) Settings
[image]

Hope it helps I had a hard time with this one